# I dont understand the CONTACT SENSOR data

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I am doing the gazebo tutorial called:
"Sensors
Contact Sensors: How to create and get data from contact sensors."

Then I followed the instructions, where I have a box with the contact sensor TAG:

```
<sensor name='my_contact' type='contact'>
          <contact>
            <collision>box_collision</collision>
          </contact>
        </sensor>
```

This box is over the ground plane.

ANd i can see the sensor  information with the instruction:
gztopic echo /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact

BUt i dont understand what does it mean.

-what does  this information mean?

```
contact {
  collision1: "box::link::box_collision"
  collision2: "ground_plane::link::collision"
  
position {
    x: -0.500000000462553
    y: 0.49999999823938179
    z: -1.3116396857526524e-11
  }
  position {
    x: 0.499999999537447
    y: 0.49999999830396458
    z: -1.3116396855009743e-11
  }
  normal {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    z: 1
  }
  normal {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    z: 1
  }
  depth: 1.3116396857526524e-11
  depth: 1.3116396855009743e-11
  wrench {
    body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"
    body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"
    body_1_force {
      x: 0.18159452738357906
      y: -0.58800230161463551
      z: 2.9400153496814356
    }
    body_2_force {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
    body_1_torque {
      x: 1.1760044494554212
      y: 1.3792103044659421
      z: 0.2032039939184285
    }
    body_2_torque {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
  }
  wrench {
    body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"
    body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"
    body_1_force {
      x: -0.18159452730762679
      y: -0.5880023016380882
      z: 2.9400153496814232
    }
    body_2_force {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
    body_1_torque {
      x: 1.1760044496335631
      y: -1.3792103043140376
      z: -0.20320399391842819
    }
    body_2_torque {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
  }
  time {
    sec: 29
    nsec: 599000000
  }
}
```

...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1448/i-dont-understand-the-contact-sensor-data./) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/516/missing-documentation-on-contact-data), and added [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/313/add-documentation-describing-data-returned/diff).  Please review and comment in issue.

To answer question in comment by @Jey_316:

1. Is the `body_1_force`, proportional to the force of the contact between the two objects?

   - `body_1_force` is the contact force exerted by the contact joint on center of gravity of the
     `collision1` Link.  And similarly, corresponding `body_2_force` will be the force exerted on
     `collision2` at the center of gravity of the corresponding link.  With the exception
     that if one of the bodies is static (e.g. groundplane, then zero force / torques are
     returned).
2. How do i know if there is not contact between the objects?

   - the `contact` array in `contacts.proto` will be empty

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on 2013-02-22**:
OK thank you, so:

1. Is the short answer of the first question  "yes"?
2. when you say CG, do you mean "center of gravity"?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-02-22**:
@Jey_316 I updated answer, hopefully it helps

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on 2013-02-27**:
Ok thanks how do i choose you as the best answer?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-28**:
@Jey_316 just click the check sign under the answer votes at top left of the answer.